# creating arrow representation on below tabs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create the following structure on click of each button i want to show small triangle representation to the center of button on the top of container
[image: tabs]

but i has no idea to achieve this. it would be helpful for suggestions and help

```css
.arrow_box {
    position: relative;
  border:2px solid green;
  height:200px;
}
.arrow_box:after {
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-bottom-color: black;
    border-width: 15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>left</button>
  <button>center</button>
  <button>right</button>
  <div class="arrow_box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The arrow needs to be positioned in relation to the upper element not the arrow box.

Answer (score 1):

Here I hacked some garbage together for you.

```css
button {
    position: relative;
}


button:focus:before{
  border:2px solid green;
  height:200px;
  width: 300px;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 200%;
  left: -20%;
  border:2px solid green;
}



button:focus:after {
    bottom: -100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-bottom-color: black;
    border-width: 15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>left</button>
  <button>center</button>
  <button>right</button>
  <div class="arrow_box"></div>
</div>
```